# Wordpres: Replace html tag with another with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

We have a problem with wordpress, we cannot use javascript to replace the `h3` tag with a `div` tag. It is a **woocomerce  mini-cart** located in the header.

```
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  
<h3>My Shoping Cart</h3> 
    
<!-- this replace with this -->
  
<div>My Shoping Cart</div> 

</div>
```

**We tried to insert javascript into the header, but it doesn't work.**

```
function ti_custom_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script>
        const h3Element = document.querySelector('.widget_shopping_cart_content h3');

        if (h3Element) {
            // Step 2: Create a new <div> element
            const divElement = document.createElement('div');

            // Step 3: Copy the content from <h3> to <div>
            divElement.innerHTML = h3Element.innerHTML;

            // Step 4: Replace <h3> with the new <div>
            h3Element.parentNode.replaceChild(divElement, h3Element);
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ti_custom_javascript');
```

**We also tried injecting the code into the footer before the  and it still doesn't replace the h3 with a div tag.**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plusmed_custom_javascript');
function plusmed_custom_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom_scripts.js','','',true);
}
```

We debugged the code and there are no errors and the file was successfully uploaded to the server.

We thought the problem was with the code, so we created a local html file where we used the same javascript and html and the tags were successfully replaced while they don't work on worpaddress.

We tried clearing the browser cache and in several browsers everything is still the same.

We try online jsFiddle and there work! only not work on server
https://jsfiddle.net/unfd18a4/

Does anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wp, but your `<script>` tag inside the function doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: what is wrong with `<script>` i tested on local and all work fine!

Comment: It seems to be inside your function, so anything outside of the <script> tags, such as `function ti_custom_javascript() {
    ?>`,  will be rendered as plain text. Also `?>` seems to be a typo.

Comment: when i put `alert(123)`  in that place whay then alert is rendered if is plain text

Comment: Where exactly is your alert?

Comment: Like i say `alert(123)` and after refresh alert is displayed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255205/discussion-between-mykaf-and-ivan).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this widget is populated via an `ajax` request.
Maybe there is some action/filter in WooCommerce or in your theme that is responsible for this. And you should first of all look for it!
But if you want to do it with js, use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const widget = document.querySelector('.widget_shopping_cart_content');

// just example of change widget content
setTimeout(() => widget.innerHTML = '<h3>My Shoping Cart</h3>', 400);

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationsList => {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      const h3 = widget.querySelector('h3');
      if (h3) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = h3.innerHTML;
        h3.parentNode.replaceChild(div, h3);
      }
    }
  }
});

observer.observe(widget, { childList: true });
```

```html
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"></div>
```